# What username should I provide when doing REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH after USER_PASSWORD_AUTH

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

What is the correct way of working with `SECRET_HASH` in AWS Cognito when doing `REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH` after `USER_PASSWORD_AUTH`?

When I do log in with an AWS Cognito user I'm using `USER_PASSWORD_AUTH` flow through which I also provide the `SECRET_HASH` composed of `clientSecret`, `clientId` & `username`:

```
const generateSecretHash = ({ clientSecret = '', clientId = '', username = '' }: InputHashData): string => {
  const message: string = username + clientId;
  const secretHash = createHmac('sha256', clientSecret).update(message).digest('base64');
  return secretHash;
}
```

```
router.post('/login', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {

  const { email, password } = req.body

  const secretHash = generateSecretHash({
    clientSecret: process.env.AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_SECRET || '',
    clientId: process.env.AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID || '',
    username: email || '',
  })

  const input = {
    AuthFlow: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH' as AuthFlowType,
    AuthParameters: {
      PASSWORD: password,
      SECRET_HASH: secretHash,
      USERNAME: email
    },
    ClientId: process.env.AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID,
  }

  try {
    const command = new InitiateAuthCommand(input);
    const response = await cognitoClient.send(command);
    res.cookie('refreshToken', response.AuthenticationResult?.RefreshToken, { httpOnly: true })
    res.send({
      message: 'Authenticated',
      data: {
        accessToken: response.AuthenticationResult?.AccessToken,
      }
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    if (err instanceof NotAuthorizedException) {
      res.status(400).send('Incorrect username or password')
    } else if (err instanceof UserNotConfirmedException) {
      res.status(200).send('User not confirmed')
    } else {
      res.status(500).send('Error while doing authentication')
    }
  }
})
```

I also have `isAuthenticated` method which tries to use the access token if still valid, but if not valid it uses the refresh token, obtained on login, to generate a new access token. The problem is that at this step I don't have the username to provide for `SECRET_HASH` so when I'm not sending the hash at all I'm getting:

`Client * is configured with secret but SECRET_HASH was not received`

While if I use only `clientSecret` and `clientId` without `username` to generate hash I'm getting:

`SecretHash does not match for the client: *`

Here is the `isAuthenticated` middleware code:

```
const isAuthenticated = (cognitoClient: CognitoIdentityProviderClient) => {
  return async (req: CheckAuthRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const { authorization } = req.headers
    const acessToken = authorization?.split(' ')[1]
    if (!acessToken) res.status(400).send('Not authenticated')
    try {
      const input: GetUserRequest = {
        AccessToken: acessToken
      }
      const getUserCommand = new GetUserCommand(input)
      const decodedToken = await cognitoClient.send(getUserCommand)
      req.userData = decodedToken
      return next()
    } catch (err: any) {
      if (err instanceof NotAuthorizedException) {
        if (!err.message.includes('expired') && !err.message.includes('Token expired')) return res.status(500).json({ message: err.message })
        try {
          const refreshToken = req.cookies.refreshToken
          if (!refreshToken) {
            return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized: Refresh token missing' })
          }
          const secretHash = generateSecretHash({
            clientSecret: process.env.AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_SECRET || '',
            clientId: process.env.AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID || '',
            username: '',
          })
          const refreshParams: InitiateAuthRequest = {
            AuthFlow: 'REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH',
            ClientId: process.env.AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID,
            AuthParameters: {
              REFRESH_TOKEN: refreshToken,
              SECRET_HASH: secretHash,
            }
          }
          const initAuthCommand = await new InitiateAuthCommand(refreshParams)
          const result = await cognitoClient.send(initAuthCommand)
          const accessToken = result.AuthenticationResult?.AccessToken
          if (!accessToken) {
            throw new Error('Access token not received in refresh response.')
          }
          req.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`
          res.cookie('refreshToken', result.AuthenticationResult?.RefreshToken, { httpOnly: true });
          return next();
        } catch (refreshError) {
          return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized: Refresh token invalid')
        }
      } else {
        return res.status(500).send('Error while doing doing authentication')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Route where middleware is user:

```
router.get('/protected', isAuthenticated(cognitoClient), async (req: CheckAuthRequest, res: Response) => {
    res.json(req.userData)
  }
)
```